# Is there a way to set buttons for QStatusBar on QDockWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import sys


class MyQStatusBar(QtWidgets.QStatusBar):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyQStatusBar, self).__init__(parent)
        self.horizontalLayout2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.horizontalLayout2.setContentsMargins(1, 1, 1, 1)


        self.toolButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.toolButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(12, 12))
        self.toolButton.setObjectName("toolButton")
        self.horizontalLayout2.addWidget(self.toolButton)

        self.toolButton_2 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.toolButton_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(12, 12))
        self.toolButton_2.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(12, 12))
        self.toolButton_2.setObjectName("toolButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout2.addWidget(self.toolButton_2)


class MainUI(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainUI, self).__init__()
        self.dock = QtWidgets.QDockWidget(self)
        bar = MyQStatusBar(self.dock)
        self.dock.setTitleBarWidget(bar)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainUI()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I want to add some custom small buttons to QStatusBar for QDockWidget，I create two ToolButtons, addWidget() to QStatusBar, but only one can be displayed Or is it inappropriate to do this on QDockWidget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> void QStatusBar::`addPermanentWidget`(QWidget *widget, int stretch = 0)
>
> Adds the given widget permanently to this status bar, reparenting the widget if it isn't already a child of this QStatusBar object. The stretch parameter is used to compute a suitable size for the given widget as the status bar grows and shrinks. The default stretch factor is 0, i.e giving the widget a minimum of space.
>
> Permanently means that the widget may not be obscured by temporary messages. It is is located at the far right of the status bar.

If I understand you correctly, then try this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import *


#class MyQStatusBar(QtWidgets.QStatusBar):                             # -
class MyQStatusBar(QtWidgets.QWidget):                                 # + QWidget
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyQStatusBar, self).__init__()
        self.horizontalLayout2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.horizontalLayout2.setContentsMargins(1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.toolButton_2 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.toolButton_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.toolButton_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.toolButton_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(12, 12))
        self.toolButton_2.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(12, 12))
        self.toolButton_2.setObjectName("toolButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout2.addWidget(self.toolButton_2)
        self.toolButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.toolButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.toolButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.toolButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(12, 12))
        self.toolButton.setObjectName("toolButton")
        self.horizontalLayout2.addWidget(self.toolButton)


class MainUI(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainUI, self).__init__()
        self.center_text = QTextEdit("center_text")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.center_text)       

        self.dock = QtWidgets.QDockWidget('Dock Window 1', self)
        self.dock.setAllowedAreas(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea | Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea)
        self.dock.setFeatures(QDockWidget.DockWidgetMovable | QDockWidget.DockWidgetFloatable)
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, self.dock)
        
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit("textEdit for Dock Window 1")
        self.bar = MyQStatusBar()
        self.status_bar = QStatusBar()
        self.status_bar.addPermanentWidget(self.bar)
        self.status_bar.setSizeGripEnabled(False)  
        self.status_bar.showMessage("Hello MyQStatusBar", msecs=7000)

        widget = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        # layout.addStretch()
        layout.addWidget(self.status_bar)
        
        self.dock.setWidget(widget)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainUI()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Wow ,Very impressive ！How did you do it? Use QT Designer?